# How to cache/reuse apollo-server resolver response

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid unnecessary calls in my resolver.

My resolvers looks like this: (minimized)

```
Transaction: {
  bkFrom(transaction) {
    return transaction.getFrom(); //<-- CACHE THIS?
  },
  bkTo(transaction) {
    return transaction.getTo(); //<-- CACHE THIS?
  },
  type(transaction) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      const [From, To] = await Promise.all([
        transaction.getFrom(), //<-- CACHE THIS? If bkFrom() is already triggered
        transaction.getTo(),  //<-- CACHE THIS? If is bkTo() already triggered
      ]);
      switch (true) {
        case From.isKonto && To.isKonto:
          resolve(TransactionType.INTERN);
        case !From.isKonto && To.isKonto:
          resolve(TransactionType.INCOMING);
        case From.isKonto && !To.isKonto:
          resolve(TransactionType.OUTGOING);
        default:
          resolve(null);
      }
    });
  },
},
```

And if I query this with something like this:

```
getTansactions(limit: 10) {
    type
    bkFrom {
      id
      name
      isKonto
    }
    bkTo {
      id
      name
      isKonto
    }
  }
```

It would call `transaction.getFrom();` and `transaction.getTo();` twice. Is there a way to avoid calling those twice? Like "caching" if its from the same request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvers for fields on the same type are going to be executed in parallel, so the resolver for `type` has no way of knowing what the resolver for `bkFrom` resolved to. I think the best way to handle this is to move that logic one level up, into the resolver for `getTansactions`.

```
getTransactions: async () {
  // Get the transactions first
  const transactions = await someCallToGetTransactions()
  // Grab all our additional calls and use Promise.all to call them concurrently
  const promises = transactions.reduce((memo, t) => {
    memo.push(t.getTo())
    memo.push(t.getFrom())
    return memo
  }, [])
  const toFrom = await Promise.all(promises)
  // Merge the results into one array
  return transactions.map((t, index) => {
    const bkTo = toFrom[index * 2]
    const bkFrom = toFrom[(index * 2) + 1]
    const type = getType(bkTo, bkFrom) //calculate type from your other fields
    return Object.assign({}, t, { bkTo, bkFrom, type })
  })
}
```

Alternatively, you could return instances of a Transaction class, and cache the values for `getTo()` and `getFrom()` that way:

```
class Transaction {
  async getTo () {
    if (!this._to) {
      this._to = await //whatever
    }
    return this._to
  }
}
```

This way, the first time `getTo()` is called, it will fetch the value and persist it in memory. Any subsequent calls to it (for that same instance) will just return the value from memory.

Comment: This would trigger the getTo() and getFrom() even if `type` and `bkFrom`/`bkTo` isn't requested, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the downside to that approach. See edit for another idea.